# calculating the area (in feet / km) of a polygon in d3 maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, map-projections

I'm trying to figure out how to get the polygon's area (eg, a town) in feet/km on my d3 map. Currently have this as a way to get the distance from one point to another

http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

I'm not sure if there's a better way of doing it?

Comment: If you're not planning to do area and distance calcs as part of the interactivity of your dataviz, wouldn't QGIS be a lot easier? e.g. Use the Distance Matrix drop-down option in QGIS on your shapefile, etc.

Comment: That stuff is much easier with Openlayers, see e.g. http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/measure.html